# "Anonymous" HTML elements added while consolidating React Providers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, anonymous-types

I am attempting to tidy my `App.js` file by using a function to inject a nested array of providers.

Previously I had something that looked like:

```
 <CreditsProvider>
   <BundlesProvider>
     <ContactsProvider>
       <PhoneVerificationProvider>
          <PurchaseProvider>
            <RanksProvider>
              <RoleWizardProvider>
                 <BasesProvider>
                   <DepsProvider>
                     <TitlesProvider>
                        <UrlsProvider>
                           <Main />
                        </UrlsProvider>
                      </TitlesProvider>
                    </DepsProvider>
                  </BasesProvider>
                </RoleWizardProvider>
              </RanksProvider>
            </PurchaseProvider>
          </PhoneVerificationProvider>
        </ContactsProvider>
      </BundlesProvider>
   </CreditsProvider>
```

I built a function to do this automatically:

```
export function BuildProviderTree(providers) {
    if (providers.length === 1) {
        return providers[0];
    }
    const A = providers.shift();
    const B = providers.shift();
    return BuildProviderTree([
        ({ children }) => (
            <A>
                <B>{children}</B>
            </A>
        ),
        ...providers,
    ]);
}
```

Back in `App.js` I fee the function the list of providers and add it to my app.

```
const Providers = BuildProviderTree(
    ...[
        HeaderBarProvider,
        CreditsProvider,
        BundlesProvider,
        ContactsProvider,
        PhoneVerificationProvider,
        PurchaseProvider,
        RanksProvider,
        RoleWizardProvider,
        BasesProvider,
        DepsProvider,
        TitlesProvider,
        UrlsProvider,
    ]
);

<NotificationBarProvider>
  <NotificationBar />
  <Providers>
     <Main />
  </Providers>
</NotificationBarProvider>
```

Everything works fine, however when I use my React dev tools to inspect the component structure I notice a bunch of nested Anonymous elements.

I have tried changing my export declaration as mentioned in a comment and this didn't work.

As I dug in a bit further I noticed all of the Anonymous elements are coming from the `<A>` elements in the function while the named providers are the `<B>` elements.

[image: Element Tree]

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong image the first time. If you look at it now you can see there are about 10 nested elements that just say Anonymous. I just don't want those in my element tree.

Comment: Yes, but what _problem_ do they cause? Are they not there when you load the components conventionally?

Comment: Correct, before I created the function to inject the providers those Anonymous elements were not there. I can't say right now that they do cause a specific problem, but I would like to clean this up before an issue is discovered.

Comment: Try to write `function BuildProviderTree(providers) {` and at the end of the page `export BuildProviderTree;` instead of `export function BuildProviderTree(providers) {`

Comment: @Giacomo How would the way the function is exported affect the structure it builds?

Comment: @DBS I don't understand it precisely, but I had Anonymous function too and with this change I removed them. Since I'm not so sure this is the same case, I try to help only with a fast comment

Comment: Do you mean `export const BuildProviderTree` at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anonymous functions are your `({ children }) => ( ... )` functions.

#### analysis

1. After applying the first & second component (`HeaderBarProvider`, `CreditsProvider`), the new array looks like this:

```
[
    ({ children }) => ( // <-- Anonymous function, new 1st element of array, will be `A` the next time
        <HeaderBarProvider>     // `A`
            <CreditsProvider>   // `B`
                { children }
            </CreditsProvider>
        </HeaderBarProvider>
    ),
    BundlesProvider, // <-- second element of array, will be `B` the next time
    ContactsProvider,
    PhoneVerificationProvider,
    // ...
]
```

2. After applying the previous & third component (`BundlesProvider`), the new array looks like this:

```
[
    ({ children }) => (       // <-- Anonymous (new first element of the array)
        ({ children }) => (   // <-- Anonymous (was previously the first element of the array)
            <HeaderBarProvider>
                <CreditsProvider>
                    <BundlesProvider>
                        { children }
                    </BundlesProvider>
                </CreditsProvider>
            </HeaderBarProvider>
        )
    ),
    ContactsProvider,         // <-- new second element of array
    PhoneVerificationProvider,
    // ...
]
```

#### possible solution

You should be aware of what happens at "React build time" (when components are created),
and what happens at "React run time" (when React creates the elements from the components).
*(the terms "build time" and "run time" might not be precisely correct here)*

- your anonymous functions, aka. React *Components* are created at "build time"
- the React *Elements* `<A>` and `<B>` are created at "run time"

With your approach - of creating one HOC (Higher Order Component) to combine 2 components at a time, at "build time" - you can not avoid creating these wrapper functions.
You can not change how the function (i.e. component) looks like, so the only way is to create a *new* component that wraps the *original* component with modified props. That *new* component is that anonymous function.

What you *can* do is you can define at "run time" how components should be rendered into elements.
I.e. you could compose the *Elements* at runtime, instead of the *Components* at build time. So you only need one HOC, which creates the elements:

```
export function BuildProviderTreeAtRuntime(originalProviders) {

    const compose = function(providers, children){
        if( providers.length < 1 ){
            return children;
        } else {
            const CurrentComponent = providers.pop();
            return compose(
                providers,
                <CurrentComponent key={'id_' + providers.length + '_' + CurrentComponent.name}>{ children }</CurrentComponent>
            );
        }
    }

    return function ComposedElements({ children }){ // <-- only one wrapper function (HOC), which creates all the nested elements
        const providers = [ ...originalProviders ];
        return compose(providers, children);
    };
}
```